# Remove data from the database when the remove button of a datatable is clicked

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, datatables, django-views

I am using a datatable to dispay information for the user and it is generated a delete button per row.

I would like to delete the row data from the database when the user click on it.

How can I do that?

**HTML**

```
...
$('#id_data').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data:data_array_data,
    "bLengthChange": false,
     //"bAutoWidth": false,
    "scrollX": true,
    "order": [[ 22, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumns" : [
                    {title:'User', sWidth: '10px', className:'dt-center' },
                    {title:'Business', sWidth: '10px', className:'dt-center' },
                    ...
                    {title:'Revenue', sWidth: '10px', className:'dt-center' },
                    {title: "",sWidth:'5px',className:'dt-center',
                            "bSortable": false,                          
                            "mRender": function() {
                                return'<button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_item_' + itemIndex++ + '"' + ' name="mybtndelete"">Delete</button>';                                                    
                            },                                               
                    },

                 ]                       
});
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def remove_register(request):
    instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=pk) "How can I obtain the pk from the datatable?"
    instance.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect your datatable to your view.
Look at this exemple:
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/REST.html

Each action of your datatable is mapped to a corresponding rest interface, you just need to call the correct url.

Comment: The link I posted shows you how you can use datatables buttons and map then to different endpoints. Here the endpoint is your view so the url you need to declare in your datatable must map to your view in your urls.py. If you want to use your own buttons like the code you posted then you will need to add your own events and Ajax call to your view endpoint. Here is an implementation using custom buttons:

Comment: https://github.com/twtrubiks/DRF-dataTable-Example-server-side/blob/master/static/js/index.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help